# when i compress .pdf files by using itextsharp dll it's not properly compress in c#.net

Tags: c#, pdf, compression, itext

I have some pdf files that contains combination of data and images when i trying to compress pdf by using itextsharp dll it's not compress properly it compress small kb of data

I am using code is:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(@"D:\File.pdf");
                PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileStream(@"D:\compressFile.pdf", FileMode.Create), PdfWriter.VERSION_1_5);          
                int pageNum = reader.NumberOfPages;
                for (int i = 1; i <= pageNum; i++)
                {
                    reader.SetPageContent(i, reader.GetPageContent(i));
                }
                stamper.SetFullCompression();
                stamper.Close();
                MessageBox.Show("Done");
}
```

Original pdf file size: 9894Kb
  After compress pdf file size : 9876Kb
  I reduce only 18Kb.
  Is it possible to compress 1000kb.
Thank you

Comment: Your observation is correct. Your code only (re-)compresses the immediate page content streams (the drawing instructions) but not any resources they refer to (images, fonts, patterns, XObjects, ...).

Comment: Hi @mkl thank you, but how can i compress pdf files is there any another way. could you please tell me

Comment: Actually your code represents the only compression easy to apply to an existing PDF using iText. You say "Is it possible to compress 1000kb" - which compression techniques are applied for that?